# how to setup a weekday in python datetime without a specific date

Tags: python, datetime, weekday

I have a string like `s = "SUN 9:30 PM"`, i.e., not a specific day, only a weekday Sunday.

How can I transform `s` to a `datetime` object?

```
from datetime import datetime
s = 'SUN 9:30 PM'
dt = datetime.strptime(s, '%a %I:%m %p')
print(dt.weekday())
```

But it looks like that python outputs `1900-01-01` and `weekday is 0`!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Why would you transform it to datetime object ?

Comment: My input is "SUN 9:30 PM", my expectation: transfer this string to a python datetime object. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat library called [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that can find a weekday in a string without a date.

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> dt = parser.parse("SUN 9:30PM")
>>> dt.weekday()
6
>>> dt = parser.parse("MON 9:30PM")
>>> dt.weekday()
0
```

This library is actually an extension of `datetime`.

Comment: This is not what I want.  Your string "'JAN 7 1993 FRI 9:30 PM" has a specific day "JAN 7 1993", but my string has no specific day. It only has "FRI 9:30 PM".  How to setup a python datetime object by strptime "FRI 9:30 PM"

Comment: I found a solution that might work for you and updated the answer.